# Google Analytics OnClick Event

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having some issues with my Google Analytics onClick events. I obviously have the google analytics code in the header:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-41953273-1', 'getafreephone.net');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Now my onclick on the hyperlink looks like the following:

```
    <a href="http://apple.freebiejeebies.co.uk/12545" target="_blank" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Click-Through', 'FreebieJeebies', 'Home Page Bottom']);"><span class="calltoaction"><img class='alignleft_action' src='images/Forward.png' alt=''/>Click here to sign up today and receive your free iPhone!</span></a>
```

However, in Google Analytics it's not picking this up at all (it's picking all page-views etc up, just not events).

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to imagine after you click on the link, you have a error in the Javascript console.

The analytics tracking code you have seems quite old, and doesn't have the `_gaq` variable available to use. I would try upgrading the tracking code that is available t at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en&ref_topic=1008079 which will give you access to `_gaq.push()`.

Also take a look at the [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) which logs a lot of useful information to the Javascript console and can help troubleshoot these issues instead of waiting 24 hours.

Comment: Works a charm, it was my analytics code that was out dated. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, the code above isn't quite old. It's in fact, quite new. It's "Universal Analytics BETA" and this code is assigned to you if you do not choose 'classic' mode.

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke he means the onclick part of the code was old!